# Is brewer's yeast a good source of protein for humans?

Tags: proteins, nutrition, digestion

I read that brewer's yeast protein is not a "real protein" and is not usable by non-ruminants. Is that true?

If yes, how can I know what kind of protein is good for humans (especially athletes)

Comment: brewers yeast is generally used as a  niacin (vitamin B3) supplement not protein. it prevents pellagra.

Comment: Please state the source. What is a “real protein”? Why would ruminants be any different from other animals? And this site is the wrong place for dietary advice.

Comment: Thank you for taking the [tour], but please also go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular it would be helpful if you were to include where you read about this and what you have done to check whether that information was true. Also note that almost all foods contain protein, but it isn't accurate to say that any of them are protein. Thanks! 